# Authentication required. http://localhost:8080 requires a username and password in Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, war, tomcat8

I am creating a war file using Maven build and tried to deploy on the localhost Tomcat 8 server.

When I try to run the war, got this

> Authentication required. http://localhost:8080 requires a username and
>   password

and message prompts for a username and password.

I am building the project using `mvn clean install` and copy the war file to the `tomcat/webapps`.

And I start the tomcat using `./catalina.sh jpda run`

What could have I done wrong? Please give some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your application.properties file

```
# turn off authentication
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got the message, Tomcat probably controls user access by `web.xml` that includes `<security-constraint>` and `<login-config>` elements or servlets that includes `@SevletSecurity` annotation defining how users are required to authenticate. So, you should check your application's `web.xml` and servlets and remove them if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check for

```
 <add type="HttpAuthModule.HttpAuthModule" name="HttpAuthModule" />
```

In your web config